# iPhone video player - Change player orientation (w/ Playlist)

Tags: iphone, video, orientation

I need to rotate the video player on iPhone (or let it autorotate).

I know the webview solution, but here come the problem, I need to play several video (distant), and WebView can't provide me a stopSelector.

I know the fact that setOrientation is a private API.

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question :

Since iOS 3.2 MPMoviePlayerViewController can just return YES to shouldAutorotate method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's none.

I know there's people that pre-rotated a movie in order to make it appear
as if it were in portrait mode, but it's a bit ugly.

update: it's supported on 3.2/4.0 using MPMoviePlayerController .

Comment: I don't need portrait mode, in need the good landscape orientation (left or right)

Comment: it's not possible with the current version of the os

Comment: which method in MPMoviePlayerController can play a move at 90 degree rotated? thx

Answer (score 0):

Try with [this](http://blog.chinaunix.net/u2/66419/showart_2160142.html):

[`moviePlayer setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];`

As you surely know, this solution will be rejected by Apple, as setOrientation for movie player is undocumented and part of the Private API.